# Select products by data attribute in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have created a new product with a custom data attribute.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$product->setName('name');
$product->setDescription('description');
$product->setPrice(1.24);
$product->setData('lid', 123);
$product->save
```

Now I want to query for this product using Mage::getModel('catalog/product').

How can I query for products with 'lid' 123?

How can I query for products where 'lid' exists aka not null?

================

Error log when performing query with addAttributeToFilter.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /Users/asdf/Sites/magento19.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  249016  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0024  514024  Mage::run( )    .../index.php:87
3   0.0085  1433456 Mage_Core_Model_App->run( ) .../Mage.php:684
4   0.0729  7141088 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch( )  .../App.php:354
5   0.0776  7404488 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match( )   .../Front.php:172
6   0.0825  7941968 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch( ) .../Standard.php:250
7   0.1205  10859488    Asdf_Sync_Adminhtml_SyncbackendController->indexAction( )   .../Action.php:418
8   0.1535  13447744    Asdf_Sync_Adminhtml_SyncbackendController->performSync( )   .../SyncbackendController.php:18
9   0.1542  13504568    Asdf_Sync_Helper_Data->pushProducts( )  .../SyncbackendController.php:33
10  0.3723  17554640    Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->addAttributeToFilter( ) .../Data.php:67
11  0.3723  17555008    Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addAttributeToFilter( )  .../Collection.php:1438
12  0.3723  17555360    Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_getAttributeConditionSql( ) .../Abstract.php:321
13  0.3723  17555472    Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->isAttributeStatic( )    .../Abstract.php:1379
```

Comment: have you created a product attribute which code is `lid`?

Comment: No I have not. Can this be done in PHP? and I assume this has to be done at module installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For create attribute run this script in your magento root directory (You can edit it by your requirements)

```
<?php  

require_once('app/Mage.php');
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();                   

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'lid', array(
             'label'             => 'LId',
             'type'              => 'int',
             'input'             => 'text',
             'backend'           => '',
             'frontend'          => '',
             'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
             'visible'           => true,
             'required'          => false,
             'user_defined'      => false,
             'searchable'        => false,
             'filterable'        => false,
             'comparable'        => false,
             'visible_on_front'  => true,
             'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
             'unique'            => false
));
$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

Now your attribute is created see i have [created](http://prntscr.com/d7yy0p)
Then set value you want [see](http://prntscr.com/d7z072)

Try This for filter product by Attribute.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('lid', 123);

foreach ($product as $products) { 
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($products);
}
```

Get product with Lid Exist

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection();


foreach ($product as $products) { 
    if($products->getLid()){
       echo $products->getName().'-->'.$products->getLid().'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working for me. and i have created attribute "technology".

Comment: I do not want to create the attribute from the backend. The module should be independent. Is it possible to create the attribute from PHP? And can you also provide a query for "How can I query for products where 'lid' exists aka not null?"

Comment: Thank you KetanKp, helped me alot. However, any idea how to get the products who have an 'lid' attribute set within the query? Looping trough all the products feels a little inefficient

Comment: i have put code below "Get product with Lid Exist" all product which have 'lid' will be listed.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can filter a product collection:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('lid', 123);

foreach ($product as $products) { /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
    // Product Collection Here
}
```

Comment: This results in an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /Users/pimreijersen/Sites/magento19.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816"

Comment: Can you share more of the exception trace? This is standard functionality, no reason it shouldn't work

Comment: Hey Robbie, trace is to long for comment, added it to the question.

Comment: This points to an incorrectly configured attribute. Did you create it with a setup script or using the admin UI?

Comment: No I have not, can the attribute be configured in PHP?

Comment: @PimReijersen yes, you can create attributes with PHP or with the admin interface. This code snippet is an example of a generic filter context in Magento. You can change the attribute and value to other that you have in your product data to see how it works. Your exception trace is caused by a mistake in your attribute configuration (most likely) - it's hard to know exactly why without seeing the configuration of your attribute (`eav_attribute` and `catalog_eav_attribute` DB tables). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one product can be loaded with

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(123,'lid')
```

If you need to load a collection

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('lid', 123);
```